# Bottom border only uses background image with gradient in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7, linear-gradients

I'm trying to design a div tag that has a linear gradient on the bottom to give it the fade effect.

I've been able to do so on Chrome, Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, etc, using the CSS below.

I used the filter and progId for Internet Explorer 7 but it gives the whole div the background and not just the bottom or top.

I think it is because, unfortunately, Internet Explorer 7 doesn't read CSS `background-size`property.

Does anyone know a way of getting the line to position at the bottom of the div tag?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div
{
padding:20px 40px; 
overflow: hidden;
background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #FFF, #000), linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #FFF, #000);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #FFF, #000), -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #FFF, #000);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 90deg, #000, #FFF, #000), -webkit-gradient(90deg, #000, #FFF, #000);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #FFF, #000), -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #FFF, #000);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #FFF, #000), -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #FFF, #000);
filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 );
background-size: 100% 2px;
background-position: 0 100%;    
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
background-color: #111111;
color:#ffffff;
}

</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#111111;">

<div>Example of what it looks like in Chrome, FF etc.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `background-position: bottom;`?

Comment: You have probably already seen this, but for reference, might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: People should just stop specifically support IE 7-

Comment: @joum thanks for replying but it doesn't do anything! If I debug, changing any of the background-position attributes does nothing to it!

Comment: @Itay if I had a choice I wouldn't be trying to support it on IE7, but unfortunately I don't have a choice so trying to do something to work round it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't so much an IE7 bug as simply IE7 not having modern browser features. Unsurprising really given how old it is.

The `filter` styles that you're using are the usual way of doing gradients in IE7, but it's absolutely non-standard, and can't be expected to work in the same way. They're external components that weren't originally designed for the web, being fudged into IE via activeX. It's not great.

You've got a few choices on how to deal with this:

1. Accept that IE7 doesn't really support gradients, and give it a plain background as a fall-back.
2. Accept that IE7 can use `filter` gradients, but that they're not very good.
3. Use a javascript polyfill such as [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) that does a better job of drawing gradients than the `filter` style.

I'll focus on this last option, as I suspect it's the one you're going to want to use. CSS3Pie hacks into IE's CSS parsing in order to allow it to support (near) standard CSS gradients (and other features).

The thing that makes it better than the `filter` style is that it uses IE's VML graphics language to render these gradients. This is much more flexible than `filter`, and does allow the kind of complex gradients you're after. There are some limitations, but in general, the results are *much* better than using `filter` for your gradients.

It also has the advantage of using standard CSS syntax, which makes it much easier to write and maintain.

The only down-side is that it is a javascript library, and it does have the potential to slow your site down if you over-use it. I haven't had a problem with this, but the key is to keep your use of this library (and polyfills in general) to a minimum; use them where it makes a real difference to your site, and where a fall-back option isn't good enough.

Hope that helps.